Related to dimension of wireless channel , transmitted signal and received signal
I am working on wireless research project and I had query in understanding dimensions.
Consider a MIMO system, where a base station with $N$ antennas transmits signal $x$ to receiver with $M$ antennas. Then the signal received at receiver is given as
$y = Hx+n$----(1)
where $H$ is channel between base station and receiver, $X$ is signal transmitted by base station and $n$ is AWGN at receiver.
My query is how do we decide the dimension of $H$, $X$ and $n$ in terms of antennas at base station and receiver.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

hey, what are the elements in your $x$? Like, what does the first entry in $x$ signify? Reading up on what $x$ actually is should solve your question. I'm a bit surprised, because you actually seem to have written the answer to your question in your question; namely, that you have $N$ transmit antennas and $M$ receive antennas. Typically, textbooks and lectures that introduce people to MIMO have a simple graphic with annotated arrows between each transmit and each receive antenna, and only from there is the existence of $H$ introduced. You don't seem to have enjoyed the same introduction!

So, from which material have you been learning the basics of MIMO? Because this is "first page" introductory information, I think you might have jumped in at the deep end and might have tried to understand research papers without reading the basics first.

Thanks a lot sir for ur reply. I am not refering to any particular textbook, but i am reading IEEE research papers and found that while writing about transmitted signal ($x$) they follow the dimension transmit antennas X receive antennas and while writing the channel, they follow the dimension receive antennas X transmit antennas. So is my understanding correct sir?

I don't understand your sentence, sorry. But really, start with a textbook. Trying to learn basics from research papers is unnecessarily hard, and takes much longer than reading the first three pages of a textbook chapter on MIMO.

Ok sir....will go through textbook
